# Conectar con servidor Postgresql desde dispositivo físico conectado al pc

Tags: java, android-studio, postgresql

Estoy intentando acceder al servidor postgresql que tengo en local desde mi dispositivo Android a través de una app de Android Studio. Si ejecuto la app en el emulador de Android Studio me funciona, pero al ejecutarla al dispositivo físico conectado al pc no me funciona. El error que me da es este:

```
W/System.err: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
W/System.err:     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:262)
W/System.err:     at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
W/System.err:     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:215)
W/System.err:     at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:404)
W/System.err:     at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:272)
W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
W/System.err:     at com.example.user.connecttodb.MainActivity$connection.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:93)
W/System.err:     at com.example.user.connecttodb.MainActivity$connection.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:75)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
W/System.err: Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 5432) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:223)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:161)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460)
W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:833)
W/System.err:     at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:61)
W/System.err:     at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:144)
W/System.err:   ... 13 more
W/System.err: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:208)
W/System.err:   ... 20 more
```

He cambiado el host que tenia, la 10.0.2.2, por localhost. También he probado con al ip del ordenador. En el fichero AndroidManifest tengo el permiso "android.permission.INTERNET" dado.

He estado buscando soluciones por la red pero no encuentro lo que estoy buscando, concretamente aquí:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626406/java-net-connectexception-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-127-0-0-1-port-9090

Por cierto, la versión de Postgresql es la 9.5.5, la de java 1.7, la de Android Studio la 2.2.3 y la de Android del dispostivo la 4.4.4.

Comment: ¿Por qué querrías acceder directamente a una base de datos desde tu dispositivo físico? ¿No sería mejor hacerlo mediante servicios? ¿Cuál es tu necesidad real que intentas resolver mediante una conexión física desde el dispositivo hacia la base de datos?

Comment: Luiggi Mendoza tiene razón pero, en caso de querer probar tal y como lo tienes, ¿has comprobado que el puerto 5432 está abierto al exterior?

Comment: Estoy practicando para realizar el proyecto final y es uno de las cosas que nos van a pedir: crear una app y una aplicación de ordenador que compartan la misma base de datos.

Comment: Que compartan la misma base de datos significa que puedan modificar los datos allí. Eso **no significa** que la aplicación móvil tenga conexión directa a la base de datos. Para ello, lo que haces es crear un proyecto base con tus entidades, dao, lógica de negocio base y se conecta a la base de datos. Luego, creas dos proyectos: uno web y otro que provee servicios web. Por último, creas el tercer proyecto que es tu aplicación Android, el cual consume los servicios de tu aplicación web de servicios.

Comment: yo tengo una aplicación android que se comunica a un servidor que tiene datos en postgress. Solo necesitas crear un servicio web (yo uso glassfish) en la que defines las request para ejecutar las funciones, obiamente la apk tendra que enviarle parametros a los request y asi correr los mantenedores

Comment: Veo que todos me comentais lo de los servicios web asi que voy a ver si lo se solucionar... Gracias, ya os iré contando... ;)